# What is the condensed formula of 2-phosphoglyceric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm looking for a simple way to visualize the position of the phosphate on 2-phosphoglyceric acid. The condensed formula seems like the best way to do this because it omits the shape of the molecule.

Answer (score 1):

What about $$\ce{HOCH2CH(OPO3H2)COOH}$$

If you really want to *visualize* the position somewhat more, coincidentally, the C-2 atom is (the only) chiral, so you could draw an asterisk above): $$\ce{HOCH2\overset{\text{*}}{C}H(OPO3H2)COOH}$$

If you think that the phosphate structure is overcondensed, you can write it somewhat more complicated way $$\ce{HOCH2CH(OP(O)(OH)2)COOH}$$
(or with square outer bracket instead).